# What's the correct two-call pattern for vkEnumerate*?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I've found two variants of the two-call pattern for `vkEnumerate*`. I'm wondering what the merit of the second solution over the first is.

The first solution:

```cpp
uint32_t count = 0;
vkEnumerateTs(ts..., &count, nullptr);
std::vector<T> results(count);
auto error = vkEnumerateTs(args..., &count, results.data());
```

What this solution doesn't take into account is that `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`
and `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties` may change at any time (see 37.4.1 of Vulkan Specification 1.2.151):

> The list of available layers may change at any time due to actions outside of the Vulkan
> implementation, so two calls to `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` with the same parameters may
> return different results, or retrieve different `pPropertyCount` values or `pProperties`
> contents. Once an instance has been created, the layers enabled for that instance will continue
> to be enabled and valid for the lifetime of that instance, even if some of them become
> unavailable for future instances.

(Similar for `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties`.)
If `count` is larger than before, you're not getting all the info;
if `count` is smaller than before, the tail of `results` contains invalid data.

Note: The results of the other `vkEnumerate*` commands seem to have infinite
life time, according to *2.5.1 Lifetime of Retrieved Results* of Vulkan Specification 1.2.151, so for the other `vkEnumerate*` commands, the first solution is sufficient:

> Unless otherwise specified for an individual command, the results are *invariant*; that is, they will remain unchanged when retrieved again by calling the same command with the same parameters, so long as those parameters themselves all remain valid.

The latter problem can be solved by extending the solution above
(`VK_INCOMPLETE` is returned if `count` is smaller than the number of properties available):

```cpp
// Check if too much space was allocated.
if (error != VK_INCOMPLETE)
{
    results.resize(count);
}
```

The second variant (taken from
[Vulkan-Tools](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Tools/blob/master/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h);
`f` is `vkEnumerateTs`, `init` serves as type sentinel for template
deduction and default value) seems to serve to solve the first problem (not getting all the info):

```cpp
// Helper for robustly executing the two-call pattern
template <typename T, typename F, typename... Ts>
auto GetVectorInit(const char *func_name, F &&f, T init, Ts &&... ts) -> std::vector<T> {
    uint32_t count = 0;
    std::vector<T> results;
    VkResult err;
    do {
        err = f(ts..., &count, nullptr);
        if (err) THROW_VK_ERR(func_name, err);
        results.resize(count, init);
        err = f(ts..., &count, results.data());
        results.resize(count);
    } while (err == VK_INCOMPLETE);
    if (err) THROW_VK_ERR(func_name, err);
    return results;
}
```

But what's the use of even trying to get "all" the info, if the amount of
available info may change at any time? Why keep iterating through the
while loop to get "complete" information if the moment you leave the
while loop to return the results, it may already be incomplete again?
Even worse, you may (theoretically) get stuck in this `while` loop forever
if the value of `count` after the first call to `f` is always smaller
than its value after the second call.

Am I misinterpreting the situation? Does the second variant
have any merit over the first (with the modification I propose)?

Comment: You are simply overthinking it. Not sure what the question exactly is as you are already listing the idiomatic scheme. The merit of the second version is that it does not trigger OCD and looks like it properly handles everything, and is only like 2 LOC longer. In other words, the code that makes the reader wonder and think less about it (and does things the straightforward obvious way) is usually the correct one. The code that wants to be "smart" about things and prematurely tries to optimize something is usually wrong.

Comment: @krOoze: I'm not sure I understand your point. The point the OP is making is that the specification states that the values returned by these particular enumeration functions are not reliable. They can change at any time. If they are potentially constantly in flux, why bother looping? The loop just creates the possibility that it will never end. Is the idea that the enumerated values will eventually settle down to some specific value? Because the spec doesn't require that.

Comment: @NicolBolas My point is that I am not sure what the OP is trying to solve as the idiomatic version is perfectly fine, robust, and hard to use wrong. What is the reason here to even look for alternatives? There is zero possibility it will never end, unless the driver is actively malicious, in which case you have much worse problems. In 99.999 % cases it wil just end after the first iteration.

Comment: @krOoze: "*the idiomatic version is perfectly fine, robust, and hard to use wrong*" And hidden. That function is not part of the Vulkan API; it's in a supplemental API. Many people don't use that supplemental API, and thus will naturally default to doing it the normal way. That's the problem with idioms; they require that you are aware that they exist. The point of the question is that, if the existing method works just as well, what's the point of the idiom? And if the existing method is unreliable, how is the idiom more reliable, since the spec says nothing that *ensures* its reliability?

Comment: @NicolBolas He asked about the pattern, not the util function. The point of the util function is to be able to swap all the `vkEnumarate*` and `vkGet*` commands and not have to write a specialization for each one by hand in error prone fashion. But he did not ask about that. As for the pattern, mostly everyone arrives at the same. Sometimes one could write the shorter version if pretty sure it is invariant, but that is error prone and requires thinking, and also why make another specialization to save one `jmp` outside a hotspot.

Comment: @krOoze If too much space was allocated, then the new `count` will be smaller than `results.size()` and `error` will be `VK_SUCCESS`. As `VK_SUCCESS != VK_INCOMPLETE`, `results` will enter the `if`-statement and resize the vector.

Comment: @mkl right I already noticed. The `if` is still unnecessary though. Either way the enumerate returns `count` of how many values it has written.

Comment: @krOoze "Either way the enumerate returns `count` of how many values it has written." - Exactly! So if `count` after the second call is smaller than `count` after the first call, then `results` is too long and still contains default values at the end, so it must be resized to `count`.

Comment: @krOoze The question is: Why keep looping if the results may be invalidated at any moment. Why not accept the first result you get (as in the first solution)? I don't see what the second (looping) version adds, other than being potentially infinite in theory.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is largely becomming opinion-based or esthetical question. I feel you are overthinking something that largely might not matter.

There is nothing wrong with either version per-se. There is also another common version that creates large enough array on the stack by estimate, and simply calls the Vulkan query once. Speaking about `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`, another option would be to skip it altogether and rely on the `VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT` only.

---

Queries are not the interesting parts of the code. And by all accounts what is the deal here is to a large part C++ification (`std::vector`, and templating to satisfy DRY principle) of the C API rather than coding something useful.

My argument here would be that the implementation that is least "smart" and least surprising is the best. Basically something that you can scan over quick and say "yep, that does what I intend and seems to properly cover all the cornercases", without thinking twice about it.

If you already got `VK_INCOMPLETE` you know for a fact the data already are incomplete, so why return data that you know for a fact are incomplete? OK, it is a fluke that would happen in 0.0001 % of cases. And OK, the data might be changed later anyway. But the question is other way around. What does the first version offer over the second version? To me it seems it only tries to be smart by skipping dealing with one of the error codes using a clever analysis of the situation. By which it gets what? Two lines of code less? The smarts and cleverness is not really warranted for this and better be used elsewhere, and the reader of the code might not expect clever stuff in mundane code.

The infinite loop case is indeed theoretical (rather I should say non-existent) problem. It would require malicious driver to actively create that situation. In which case you have bigger problems.

Comment: "OK, this is largely becomming opinion-based or esthetical question." - True. Thanks for writing up an answer!